# Spring MongoDB query sorting

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, sorting

I'm fairly new on mongodb, and while I'm trying to make ordered mongodb query. But spring data mongodb's sort method is deprecated. So I used `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort`:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC,"pdate"));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Product.class);
```

I used this code block. But its not sorting the data. So can you prefer to use any useful method for this practice?

Comment: Your code looks correct, can you elaborate how did you come into conclusion "its not sorting the data"

Comment: they are not ordered date ascending on the page

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can define your sort in this manner to ignore case:

```
new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, FIELD_NAME).ignoreCase()
```

Comment: thanks , that was what I mean years ago in my answer, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: You can actually pass a comma delimited list (or pre-constructed List) to the Sort constructor and define multiple ordering criteria!

Comment: It doesn't work at me, with newest MongoDb, strange...    I've got exception with Mongo and code like that... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given sort contained an Order for username with ignore case! MongoDB does not support sorting ignoreing case currently!

Comment: This is deprecated now. Use Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, FIELD_NAME)) instead

Answer (score 24):

**NEW ANSWER** - Spring Data Moore

Use `Sort.by`

```
Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("field").`is`(value)).with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "sortField"))
```

Answer (score 17):

When you've written a custom query in your repository then you can perform sorting during invocation. Like,

**Repository**

```
@Query("{ 'id' : ?0}")
List<Student> findStudent(String id, Sort sort);
```

**During invocation**

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "date")
List<Student> students = studentRepo.findStudent(1, sort);
```

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 7):

This is how you sort a field value by Descending order.
My field value is "nominationTimestamp", but for you it could be "firstName" for example.

```
List<Movie> result = myMovieRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "nominationTimestamp"));
```

myMovieRepository is an instance of whatever class extends MongoRepository<>.

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code. Codes without any explanation are going to be deleted.

Answer (score 6):

```
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "timestamp"));
```

remember sort parameter as field, 1 or -1 to specify an ascending or descending sort respectively.

Comment: Can we use query.with() to sort on multiple fields ?
e.g 
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "timestamp")).with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"name"));

Answer (score 4):

You can use aggregation for sorting your data. You have to use matching and grouping criteria for aggregation query and unwind your field.

```
AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(matching criteria);
AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("fieldname");
AggregationOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "fieldname");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.unwind("fieldname"),match,group,sort);
```

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me:

```
query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("pdate")));
```

Answer (score 2):

### `spring-data-commons` version 2.3.5+

The `Sort` constructor is private, so:

```java
Query query = new Query();
query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC,"pdate"));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Product.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Aggregation in repository

**Repository**

```java
  @Aggregation(pipeline ={
    "{$match: { id : ?0 }",
    "{$sort: {date: 1}}",
    "{$limit: 1}"
  }
  Optional<Student> findStudent(String id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using TypedAggregation with mongoTemplate in spring data to sort and limit the results set.

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.limit;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.match;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.newAggregation;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.project;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.sort;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;

TypedAggregation<ObjectType> agg = newAggregation(ObjectType.class,
    match(matching Criteria),
    project("_id", ...),
    sort(Direction.ASC, "_id"),
    limit(pageSize));

List<RESULT_OBJECT> mappedResult = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, COLLECTION_NAME, RESULT_OBJECT.class).getMappedResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always need to sort data in same direction add this to repository:

```java
@Query(sort = "{'view': -1}")
Page<BlogModel> findTopBlogList(Pageable pageable);
```